# ActiveMQ Classic: permission to write to DLQ

Tags: activemq-classic, amazon-mq, dlq

For testing and debugging purposes we would like to give permission to a user to write directly to DLQ. Is it possible to state that somehow in the configuration file?

I have tried adding the dlq explicitly to the user's group list but that did not work.

Comment: Do you have an `authorizationPlugin` defined in your `activemq.xml`?

Comment: yes we have, and that specific user have permission to the topic (which means to it's queues as well) but when I want to write to DLQ I get this: 
org.springframework.jms.JmsSecurityException: User ****** is not authorized to write to: queue://DLQ.***.***.***.queue

Comment: Please add the `authorizationPlugin` configuration from `activemq.xml` to your question as well as the code sending the message to the DLQ.